# Windows Phone 8 Music App 'forgetting' artist details

Tags: sync, music, mediaplayer

I imported some music onto my Nokia Lumia 820 recently. I've been having problems, so I've deliberately only synced a minimal amount of music. When I synced it, I immediately checked and everything seemed ok. Now a few days later, the music app has 'forgotten' the artist details of about 70% of the music. Most artists now come up under `Unknown`, despite having full ID3 tags which **were** recognised previously.

Anyone have any idea what's going on?

EDIT: The problems I've been having involve Windows Media Player creating duplicate entries in the Media library, so I'll sync an album and end up with multiple entries for the same file.

Comment: Try using iTunes as your new media player. i know its for apple devices but i use it to organize my music. download the windows phone app from here https://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/how-to/wp8/windows-phone-app-for-desktop . this app is pretty simple and you have an option to import from iTunes. iTunes does a better job of organizing your music easily. it is indeed very sad Microsoft doesn't integrate its products very well.

Comment: Thanks Zany. This issue has been resolved in Windows Phone 8.1 so it's no longer an issue for me

Comment: I takes some time to,load. I will suggest you to store music on phone memory rather than sd card memory.

Comment: That's a bad idea. The SD card is exists for a reason, and that reason is storage for things that take up lots of room. If you store music on the phone memory, you won't fit much before you start running seriously low on space. I know this because I've since upgraded to a Lumia 925 which has no SD card (why oh why do so many premium phones not have SD cards when all budget phones seem to?) Now I can't store nearly as much music. I think I have like 10 albums on there and I occasionally get warnings if I let my camera roll build up. 

USE THE SD CARD FOR MUSIC!